# symfony2 store uploaded file non rootweb

Tags: symfony, upload, twig, x-sendfile

I have problem with uploading files, I'm saving uploaded files in a non public folder (non webroot folder), and then I want to get the webPAth of all uploaded files to use them in a video gallery.

```
$videos = $repository->getVideosThumbs($this->getUser());
```

and then in my twig

```
{% for video in videos %}
         <a href ="{{ path('neoctus_videobundle_default_watchvideo', {'id' : video.id, 'salt' : app.user.salt }) }}" >
            <img id="{{ video.id }}" src="/uploads/images/{{video.imgPath}}" alt="1st image description" height="150" width="150"  />
         </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

but I can not access the pictures because the folder is not public, I know I have to go through x-sendFile but I do not see how I can send multiple jpeg files in the header and then how recover after the twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a controller action to access files that are stored in a non public folder. In that action, you open file and stream in to browser.

See example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

You will need to change

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
```

to

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($file));
```

**UPDATE:**

When you have your controller action that would stream requested file, you can render it in your TWIG by requesting that action with required file identifier:

```
<img src="{{ path('route_to_stream_action', {'fileId':'some_id'}) }}">
```

Browser will treat streamed file the same way as if it was accessed directly, so you can apply any CSS to it.

**UPDATE:**

Sample controller action:

```
public function streamFileAction($fileId)
{

    // implement your own logic to retrieve file using $fileId
    $file = $this->getFile($fileId);

    $filename = basename($file);

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($file){
        $handle = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'rb');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fread($handle, 1024);
            echo $buffer;
            flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
    });
    $d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $filename);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $file->getMimeType());

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
but I know how to read a file directly on my browser, what I need is how can I send those files to my twig so I can apply on them some css .. any idea ?!

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "controller" function in twig:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:Controller:action')) }}
```

will launch

the actionAction in ControllerController in AcmeBundle.

Hope this helps somehow.