# Show image from path out of root

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have 2 web applications:

- Administration
- Client

I use Administration to upload photos into folder on server. And I want to load photos in Client.
Img tag can read only from root directory and its subfolders, but I have files in /var/www/uploads.

Is some result for my issue?

I use Symfony2 and Twig.

**EDIT:**
Solve is here: [symfony2 store uploaded file non rootweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880785/symfony2-store-uploaded-file-non-rootweb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your uploads directory isn't accessible from browser, than you gonna have to create `Controller` to read the file and return it as response. Luckily Symfony already provides File response which will stream the file.

More information in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't want to response file to download, but get more files in the response time to display in view.
Something like array of files for display.